# Build fail after updating Xcode 13.4.1

Tags: xcode, flutter, build-error

After Updating Xcode(version 13.4.1), iOS build keep failing.

I tried to update CommandLineTools as people said in forums, but it doesn't fix the error.

This is the log when the build fails.

```
2022-07-30 18:05:16.911 xcodebuild[76975:2182596] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-07-30 18:05:16.911 xcodebuild[76975:2182596] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-07-30 18:05:17.371 xcodebuild[76975:2182598] Unable to locate a bundle at URL file:///Users/username/Downloads/Xcode%202.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes/iPhone%2011%20Pro.simdevicetype/
2022-07-30 18:05:17.371 xcodebuild[76975:2182598] Unable to locate a bundle at URL file:///Users/username/Downloads/Xcode%202.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/
** BUILD FAILED **
```

If someone had a same problem and solved it, please help